# Google Cloud - Active Connections on Cloud SQL with Autoscaling

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have set up 2 Instances in a VM Group which have the same standard Joomla installation. The common database is hosted on Cloud SQL. I have then setup a load balancer on the group.

The problem is number of active connections on Cloud SQL start rising on its own and reaches 250 connections (maximum connections within the tier i selected). The server then starts showing "Cannot connect to database". At that moment, there were about 10-15 visitors on the website so there is no chance of getting so many active connections with the database. I have to then reboot both the instances manually to kill all the connections.

If i create a single VM Instance and Cloud SQL to host the website (without load balancer), then the active connections never crosses 10-12 active connections.

Do i need to follow some rules when using load balancer(Autoscaling) to eliminate such problem?

Comment: Is this a network load balancer, HTTP/S load balancer, or something custom running on a VM?

Comment: Can you please provide the present health check you are implementing on your cloud loadbalancer. Also is the loadbalancer a network or http loadbalancer?

Comment: it is an HTTP/S load balancer created using the dashboard. the health check is an HTTP check which occurs every 5 seconds and is targeted on a txt file present in a folder (/check/file.txt)